# Swift UICollectionView inside UITableView onItemSelect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a layout much like the iOS App Store. I have followed this tutorial: http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

Everything is working but the problem is that this tutorial does not cover tapping on a UICollectionView cell and segueing to a new UIViewController. Has anyone implemented that? I am new at Swift, so I need a little help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to go to your ViewCollectionController and override the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourControllerIdHere") as UIViewController
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

if you have a segue set up already then just do

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSeguesIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I have no ViewCollectionController. My UICollectionView is inside of the TableViewCell object. I do not have access to things like performSegueWithIdentifier() or self.storyboard. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually got this functional. Probably not the most efficient, but like I said, Swift is not my wheelhouse. Anyway I just passed an instance of the UIViewController that contains the UITableView into the TableViewCell. Then I call performSegueWithIdentifier() like in Usernumbernine's answer.